# Different ways of executing tasks

Tags: c#

Could anyone please explain the difference between following two pieces of C# code?

```
var tasks = new List<Task<CustomTaskResult>>();
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => AsyncMethod1());
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => AsyncMethod2());
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => AsyncMethod3());
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => AsyncMethod4());
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

and

```
var tasks = new List<Task<CustomTaskResult>>();
tasks.Add(AsyncMethod1());
tasks.Add(AsyncMethod2());
tasks.Add(AsyncMethod3());
tasks.Add(AsyncMethod4());
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: first one uses thread and second one asynchronous functions which returns a task object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one queues four method executions to the thread pool, and then asynchronously waits for them all to complete.

The second one starts four method executions on the current thread, and then asynchronously waits for them all to complete.

Comment: So does this mean the first one is similar to `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: @Jaya: It's similar in the sense that it uses the thread pool. Everything else is different.